# Emma code coverage for a lib on Android

Tags: android, ant, code-coverage, emma

I currently have some unit tests for an Android app, which makes calls to a library jar file. I would like to see the code coverage for the jar, but when I run ant emma and look at the coverage.html, it only reports on the coverage of the app project.

Is there a way to specify that I would like to view the coverage for the jar as well?

Comment: did u get it to work? I am still getting only the App not the library. I added  the "tested.project.lib.source.path" in ant.properties and made it point to my libary/src folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ADT r20-preview solves this issue by giving access to the full classpath of tested projects and their Library Projects:

http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview

> Fixes in Ant:
>
> - Test projects now have access to the full classpath from the tested projects, including Library Projects and 3rd party jar
> - Applications embedding tests can now be deployed and tested, including with code coverage, like test applications.

This will give you code coverage reports on your library projects, but you will have to do some modifying of the `test` target of `build.xml` to attach the source files too. See [Attach Android library project source code to Emma report (ant, emma)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32421) for more information on how to incorporate emma test coverage for your library projects for the time being.

Comment: Hey, I just checked out that tutorial, and I have a question. That path under: "# This can be a semicolon delimited list of directories
                tested.android.library.source.dir=../library/src;etc", is that the location of my android source? What does the author mean by "/library/src/etc"?

Comment: @NioShobu That is a semi-colon delimited list of your library project source directories.

Answer (score 0):

The Emma documentation mentions instrumenting jars ( http://emma.sourceforge.net/ ) so it seems possible, perhaps you need to play with the configuration settings a bit.

Good luck.