# Ant/Emma Instrumenting Android SDK

Tags: android, ant, code-coverage, emma

I am currently trying to test the Android SDK/API, and to do so have created an application that utilizes the SQLite classes in the API as well as a test that runs that application. I have been desperately trying to find code coverage of the SDK so that I can analyze my tests and get some actual results for my project. However, I can not seem to find any documentation (or even Stack Overflow questions) that provide any help for me to do this. I have been playing around with EMMA (and for a while Ant, although apparently the version in my Android build is not sufficient, and downloading it separately didn't go well for me). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419331/emma-code-coverage-for-a-lib-on-android) question before, but I don't get their solution.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

EDIT: I tried adding the code from the preceding link's link (it's adding code to the build.xml and ant.properties for EMMA), but now I don't even know where the coverage logs are stored, if it even works like I think it might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run code coverage on my Android projects using [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/). My unit tests are setup to run using [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/). I haven't used Ant to manage my Android builds, but it shouldn't be difficult getting it to work with these.

Comment: Two things: 1) Does using EclEmma give me coverage of the Android source classes (i.e. SQLiteDatabase, which I am using) and not just my test? The whole purpose of what I am doing is to test the Android API, so I need coverage of those classes. 2) I tried using EclEmma, but I get a weird error: "Error while dumping coverage data (code 5013).
Socket closed"

Comment: Assuming you have the source code for the Android SDK attached to your project, yes it should. Although I find it a little strange you need to test Android's code. I don't know what that second issue is.

Comment: I updated, and it seems to work now, but I'm getting an error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2"

Comment: After looking it up some, I found someone mention that it might be because Java 1.7 doesn't support EclEmma (or I think the other way around), but I'm using 1.6.0.33... Do I need to downgrade so little just to get this to work?

Comment: I use regular JUnit for my Android testing, but it looks like the Android test classes (i.e. ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`) aren't in your classpath.

Comment: How should I change that in my settings?

Comment: I looked in Coverage Configurations > ClassPath and see the Android 4.1 library in there under "Bootstrap Entries". Doesn't this mean it is included in the classpath?

Comment: Presumably in your test project's classpath. I don't think this has anything to do with EclEmma.

Comment: Where do I change that in Eclipse's settings, though? This works fine when running normally on the emulator, I just get it when I run coverage with EclEmma.

Comment: Adding `android.jar` specifically to the User Entries under classpath results in a `Stub!` error.

Comment: Right, Robolectric is used to avoid the stub issues.

Comment: By the way, how would I be able to see the coverage of the Android libraries if I run EclEmma?

Comment: You will need to attach the source code to your project. It won't work if you're just using the binaries.

Comment: How so? Just link something to the source code in my AOSP directory? Where would that be in the settings?